# AWS EC2 limit error while updating EC2 instance of Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While updating EC2 instance of Elastic Beanstalk the following error message appeared. But for my other account the following error, not observed:

> Updating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-tiknsbmh4d-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-R3UXFI8KMCSN failed Reason: You have requested more instances (1) than your current instance limit of 0 allows for the specified instance type

Is it account base specific? And what is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are limits which are account-specific.

You can check your EC2 quotas using the AWS Quota Service. [1]
You can view the EC2 quotas which apply for the account you are currently signed in by visiting the following URL: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=REGION#!/services/ec2/quotas by replacing *REGION* with your [region identifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html), e.g. *us-east-1*.

If the quota is marked as *adjustable*, you can request an increase via this service.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

This message is related to Amazon EC2. Even though the instance was launched by Elastic Beanstalk, the limit is related to the number of concurrent Amazon E2 instances permitted.

There are two types of limits:

- Total number of concurrent instances (default: 20)
- Number of concurrent instances per instance type (default varies)

You can view these limits in the **Limits** section of the Amazon EC2 management console. You can also **request an increase in the limits**.

The limits are "per account, per region".